# Why is my google account authentication failing?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

I have created a scraping application ( C# ) that writes results to a private Google Sheet.

When I run the application in Debug mode, it works as expected and authenticates.
However, when I run it as a task, the authentication fails here...

```
 using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```

I have a credentials.json file set to copy always in the project and it is being copied to the bin/debug and bin/release folders on compilation.

The error I am getting (only when run in task scheduler) is this....

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\credentials.json'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, 
   FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean 
   bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at ScreenScraper.Program.AuthorizeGoogleApp() in 
   C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 
   2017\Projects\ScreenScraper\ScreenScraper\Program.cs:line 74
   at ScreenScraper.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual 
   Studio 2017\Projects\ScreenScraper\ScreenScraper\Program.cs:line 38
```

---

I then copied credentials.json to C:\WINDOWS\system32\ but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Permission issue perhaps?

Comment: Possibly - I gave full read permission to the folder - same error

Comment: I suggest you choode a different path tham Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal, e.g. Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonAppData

Comment: @KlausGütter - I tried that - same error : Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\credentials.json

Comment: When I run the exe directly from the bin/debug it works ... so must be a setting in the task scheduler

Comment: You might want to pass a complete path to `new FileStream()`. Relying on the current directory is often not a good idea.

Comment: @KlausGütter - just to be complete , i tried the full file path, but still the same error

Comment: I would be very surprised if you got the *exact same error* (namely that `C:\WINDOWS\system32\credentials.json` can't be found) if you specify the full path. Exactly how did you specify it?

Comment: string credPath = @"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\.credentials.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json";

Answer (score 2):

In actions change optional start up to the folder path. 
Actions > Edit > Program/script = YOurGoogle.exe > Start in (Optional) >  eg.C:\Users\Me\